# Predicates and lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, predicate

I have recently moved to .net 3.0 (windows forms, C#). I want to know more about predicates and lambda expressions. Where should we use them? Do they improve performance? and how do they work internally. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search Stack Overflow you'll find about a thousand answers explaining what they're for. In short - a lambda is a way of writing an anonymous method at the point where you want to pass it to another method. Technically the same as the `delegate` syntax for an anonymous method, although with added powers of type inference so you don't need to state the parameter types. A predicate is a method that accepts some value and returns a `bool` - an example would be the argument to `Where`.

A lambda that doesn't refer to any external variables gets turned into a private static method with a made-up name. If it refers to instance members of the enclosing class, it becomes an instance method. If it refers to local variables, those variables get "hoisted" into being fields of a compiler-generated class that is allocated when the enclosing method starts running, and the lambda's body becomes a method in that new class.

As for performance, they don't make that much difference. They involve the creation of temporary objects, but [I find that these are collected extremely efficiently by the GC](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/the-amazing-speed-of-the-net-garbage-collector/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to study the different versions of C# and how they different .My suggestion is read the book C.Sharp.in.Depth by jon skeet . This will give you the better understanding of new versions

Answer (score 0):

> Do they improve performance? and how
>   do they work internally. Thanks.

For the most part, you'll never notice the performance hit. However, there are some pathological cases which will kill performance, namely overzealous use of [fixed point combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator).

Its a well-known trick that we can use the Y-combinator to write recursive lambda functions, however consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace YCombinator
{
    class Program
    {
        static Func<T, U> y<T, U>(Func<Func<T, U>, Func<T, U>> f)
        {
            return f(x => y<T, U>(f)(x));
        }

        static int fibIter(int n)
        {
            int fib0 = 0, fib1 = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                int tmp = fib0;
                fib0 = fib1;
                fib1 = tmp + fib1;
            }
            return fib0;
        }

        static Func<int, int> fibCombinator()
        {
            return y<int, int>(f => n =>
            {
                switch (n)
                {
                    case 0: return 0;
                    case 1: return 1;
                    default: return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
                }
            });
        }

        static int fibRecursive(int n)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0: return 0;
                case 1: return 1;
                default: return fibRecursive(n - 1) + fibRecursive(n - 2);
            }
        }

        static void Benchmark(string msg, int iterations, Func<int, int> f)
        {
            int[] testCases = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 20 };
            Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i <= iterations; i++)
            {
                foreach (int n in testCases)
                {
                    f(n);
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", msg, watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int iterations = 10000;
            Benchmark("fibIter", iterations, fibIter);
            Benchmark("fibCombinator", iterations, fibCombinator());
            Benchmark("fibRecursive", iterations, fibRecursive);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints out:

```
fibIter: 14.8074
fibCombinator: 61775.1485
fibRecursive: 2591.2444
```

fibCombinator and fibRecursive are functionally equivalent and have the same computational complexity, but fibCombinator is a full 4100x slower due to all of the intermediate object allocations.

Comment: It should perhaps be remembered that no C# programmer (or indeed, any user of a post-Algol language) would ever use the Y-combinator to achieve recursion, unless they wanted to teach themselves about the history of languages lacking a built-in concept of a named function that can refer to itself.

Comment: @Earwicker: good point :) You'd never write code like this in C#, but combinators and point-free style are all the rage in F#, OCaml, and Haskell. I've experimented with combinators and point-free style in F#, and in almost all cases the combinator version slows performance to a crawl.